# In AMP pages default css of the components is not working

Tags: amp-html

My HTML file code is :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ⚡="">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Amp</title>
      <link rel="canonical" href="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
      <script async="" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
      <style amp-boilerplate=""></style>
      <script custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp- 
                     carousel-0.1.js" async=""></script>
      <style amp-custom=""></style>
    </head>
    <body> 
      <header class="ampstart-headerbar">
             Amp pages
      </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I open this file in my browser then `style` for `header` does not inject. In  AMP pages If I want to give the custom style then I need to give this in the internal style with `amp-custom` attribute but why AMP component style is not injecting? I am unable to understand what library is missing in this code? I am exploring AMP first time. If there are some more suggestions which I need to take care then please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way `amp-custom` need to be defined.

Try adding the CSS from the below file from the line 39 - 41. That should fix the issue.
https://github.com/saichandu415/AMP-Ecommerce-Apsara/blob/master/Website/templates/landing.amp.html

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
            <script custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js" async></script>  
    ...
    <style amp-custom>
      /* any custom styles go here. */
      body {
        background-color: white;
      }
      amp-img {
        border: 5px solid black;
      }

      amp-img.grey-placeholder {
        background-color: grey;
      }
    </style>
    ...
  </head>
```

Check this below link for more detailed information

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive_amp

Let us know if this helped. Thanks!

Comment: when I am adding header then the css is not injecting. For e.g. `<header class="ampstart-headerbar"></header>` css is not injecting in this. There is no style in the browser when I inspect. Is there css library which I need to include or do I need to write my own css on the basis of ampstart-headerbar.

Comment: I assume you are following tutorial or article, I am unable to find any class `"ampstart-headerbar"` in your amp-custom tag

Comment: I am following this link: (https://www.ampstart.com/components#buttons)

Comment: updated the answer with additional scripts, can you try now?

Comment: I have added a link to the answer, copy the css from line 39 - 41 that should fix the issue.

Comment: Hey!! yeah, this is working now... why that CSS is needed?? and how did you get to know this CSS?

Comment: Great!! the templates you are referring to uses `basscss & normalize.css`.That is not mentioned in the documentation but in the full templates. Please upvote and accept as correct answer that helps others and me too :)

Comment: Hey!! Please tell me why that CSS is needed?? and the doc which I am following and shared with you they have not mentioned about this custom CSS anywhere..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173713/discussion-between-smelter-and-vishakha-nehe).